# How can I programmatically store a birthday with no year in Android?

Tags: android, date, format

Most/all Android contact apps allow users to specify a yearless birthday (checkmark to exclude year in some UI's).
How is it possible to programatically store such a yearless date in the contact database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android yearless dates look like this when they come back from the DB:
--MM-dd
So the key to putting yearless date in is to mimick that format - use a DateFormat of
--MM-dd, and take the resulting string and put it in. Voila, the UI will show the birthday as a yearless date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("--MM-dd");
return sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Note that MM-dd  won't work. You'll see an MM-dd formatted string in your Birthday field in the Contacts app, but it will not be editable. The --MM-dd format will produce a result that will use the Contact's app date format, and also when you click on it the date editor will open.

While we're on the subject, note that IOS uses the year "1604" to represent a yearless date. 
That's because IOS insists on storing the date as an exact moment (millisecond).
Android actually stores the info in string format.